# Check if Java bytecode contains debug symbols during runtime

Tags: java

Is there an interface to `java.lang.Object`, where you can find out, if the running byte code was build with `javac '-g'` switch or not?

Depending on that I want to choose different parameter sets automatically during run-time, without additional configuration from outside.

Comment: Something hackish like `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber() > 0` comes to mind.

Comment: Since every class file can have a different setting (and the setting can have multiple values), the first question is: how do you want to treat a mixed batch of class files? Is this for some kind of security/copy-protection related task?

Comment: @zapl That's good for checking the line number table, but there are other settings too, which can probably only be detected if you write your own class loader and disseminate each class file on loading. It's probably more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: not sure how I would go about variable names ([maybe?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html)) but the [other `-g`](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/javac-g-Controlling-Debugging-Information.html) options can be tested via [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) as well (worst case against known values). Should be sufficient to decide between a few build configurations, for general purpose I guess the best bet is something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/7995377 i.e. inspecting bytecode

Comment: @zapl Completely forgot about `Method.getParameters()`, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Just a nitpick: I think it is even compliant to the class file format spec to have a single class where *one* method has debug information (like line numbers), and *another* method has not. (Although `javac` can not generate such files by default, they might still exist...)

Comment: BTW: For a test, I wrote a class that uses [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) to load a `.class` file, and correctly determines the `none`, `source`, `lines` and `vars` settings that have been used to create the file. But at runtime, you'll probably have to use workarounds like those suggested so far (and the source file name could, at best, be determined indirectly...)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The solution with calling 'getLineNumber() > 0' is enough for my purpose, because I only use this recognition in my main and make suggestions for the rest. I am not interested in every used class, because 90% is still third party and not under my control ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to find methods for accessing debug information using [Apache BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).