# Java/groovy reflection read method content

Tags: java, reflection, methods, groovy, reverse

i would like to analyse my code, classes and methods : my goal is to create a sequence diagram by reversing my code
But , i would like to analyse it without running the application

So, i already get my classes and methods names
What i am looking for now , is to **read/get the content of a method** , without using a regex expression to parse my entire file
Is there a simple way to get it ?
Thanks

Comment: Use a `JarInputStream` (if content is JAR) to acquire bytes of individual classes, and then use a bytecode engineering library (such as ASM) in order to analyze bytecode.

Comment: why not create diagram from your sorce code?

Comment: @Vulcan : thanks, i don't make any JAR yet, but it's an idea to do it in order to analyse it in a second time

Comment: Example for ASM use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984003/pretty-printing-a-method-in-asm-bytecode

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Groovy's [Global AST Transforms](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Global+AST+Transformations) to analyze your code. It will give you access to the abstract syntax tree. From there you can walk in the tree nodes of your code. This is 'hooking' in the Groovy compilation process.

I'm not sure it will work with Java code. Java is Groovy code, so in theory it could work, but the compiler won't go through `.java` files.

Comment: Hi, it seems to be a good direction ,thanks, but i don't really like the fact to be obliged to add annotation "everywhere". Maybe i still have to learn more on AST, but it's not simple :/

Comment: No, global asts don't need annotations everywhere! Also, i just noticed, but "Since Groovy 1.7.5, you are allowed to add your own file types to the groovy compiler"