# View class bytecode at runtime

Tags: java, netbeans, bcel

I have patching class dynamycly by BCEL, and them I dynamycly reload class.
I`m not sure what I really reloading class.

How can I check it?

How can I view class bytecode without save it as file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure what I am really reloading the class.  How can I check it?

Well, you could print a message to `System.out` in static initializer in your class.  If the message is printed you will know that your class has been reloaded, and the (new) class has been initialized.

> How can I view class bytecode without save it as file?

See [Pretty printing a method in ASM Bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984003/pretty-printing-a-method-in-asm-bytecode)

> Whether netbeans special instruments for it?

I don't know what you are asking here ...